# Is there a pronunciation difference between the noun "display" and the verb "display"?

Tags: pronunciation, heteronyms

I know that in English, the emphasis on one syllable or the other is based on whether the word is a noun or a verb.
[For example](http://www.english-for-students.com/Heteronyms.html):

> Contract CONtract- an agreement; conTRACT- to shrink or to agree on a project

> Record RECKord- a list; reKORD- to write down

> Subject SUBjekt- the theme; subJEKT- to force upon someone

My question is if this also applies to the noun display and the verb to display. My instinct would be to pronounce the first **DISplay** and the latter **disPLAY**, but I didn't find anything to confirm this.

Is this word always pronounced the same, and if so, is there a reason?

Comment: The pattern is somewhat irregular. There are no fixed rules in English. "Display" -> disPLAY -- both noun and verb.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to note is that American English and British English very often have different "rules" for this, as do other varieties of English.

The second thing to note is that the "rules" are inconsistent even within any particular version of English.

All I can say for sure is that in England we say  *disPLAY* for both verb and noun. I believe the same is true in America.

**My suggestion**

Decide which version of English you wish to learn, then find a good online pronunciation dictionary. Most good ones have the speaker symbol so you can hear the word spoken,

[image]

For example wordreference even allows you to hear  [different pronunciations](https://www.wordreference.com/definition/display) according to country.

[image]

Comment: 'The first thing to note is that American English and British English very often have different "rules" for this, as do other varieties of English.

The second thing to note is that the "rules" are inconsistent even within any particular version of English.' _So what is the specifying definition for 'American English'? 'British English' etc? These terms are not well-defined and in my opinion misleading. 'Most Brits would say ...' is getting more reasonable._

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth - That is a useful comment. However, if you read my answer carefully, I think you'll find I hedged it sufficiently.   My main intention was summed up in the second sentence of my answer. Note that there are at least some rules that differ. One is of course the difference in spelling - "color" versus "colour" for example.

Comment: The very terms 'American English' and 'British English' are ill-defined and thus misleading, and I rarely use them, and never outside scare quotes.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth - You may be interested in the following video [20 Words Brits and Americans Say Differently](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lCYL0jOcrtQ) it seems quite accurate.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It’s common here to distinguish between AmE and BrE when there are clear differences between them that are relevant to learners, no matter how fuzzy the distinction may be in general.

Comment: No; I've done studies on regional differences. Some differences between word choice, certainly pronunciation, and even which expressions are considered acceptable within the UK, especially in speech, make the concept of 'British English' unworkable. And to take two examples the -ise v -ize spelling choices, and acceptability of notional agreement with say collective/group nouns, while often labelled as each constituting a 'BrE' v 'AmE' dichotomy, are far from nation-specific. Wikipedia essentially concedes that 'BrE' is an unworkable term for the spoken language variants in the UK.

Answer (score 1):

Note that much of any difference in pronunciation results from the different ways nouns are used vs verbs.

The noun "display" commonly comes at the end of a phrase or sentence, where there is a natural pause in speech.  And even when the word is used as a part of a compound noun ("display adapter", "display cable", etc) the pronunciation tends to not be "rushed".

But the verb "display" is almost always used in a transitive context ("display the text"), and there's a natural tendency to merge the word with the following word.  This has a subtle effect on how the word is pronounced.

Answer (score 0):

You can be pretty confident that **if** a noun and verb with the same spelling have stress on different syllables, the noun will have stress earlier (further "to the left") than the verb.

But it is not a general rule that a noun and verb with the same spelling will have stress on different syllables. Many have stress on the same syllable: for example, aside from *display,* there's *disdain, disguise, disgust, dissent, dishonor* which all can be used as nouns or verbs and have stress on the second syllable either way.

The same pronunciation pattern can apply to words not starting with *dis-*, such as *collapse, concern, command, report, decay.*

Unfortunately, I don't know of any rule that would let you predict whether a verb and a noun have stress on different syllables or on the same syllable.